# How to get Current User address every time in init State?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am using GeoLocation and GeoCoding in my app but the address was always return null

```
  Position? _currentPosition; >>>> always return null
 String? _currentAddress;
 String key = "location_cache";
 _getCurrentLocation() {
Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        forceAndroidLocationManager: true)
    .then((Position position) {
  setState(() {
    _currentPosition = position;
  });

  _getAddressFromLatLng();
}).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
}

_getAddressFromLatLng() async {
 try {
   List<Placemark> p = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
      _currentPosition!.latitude, _currentPosition!.longitude);

  Placemark place = p[0];

  setState(() {
    _currentAddress = "${place.locality}";
  });
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

```
@override
void initState() {
  _getCurrentLocation();
  super.initState();
print(_currentAddress);
}
```

I WANT TO GET THE USER location every time he  go to this screen ??
then I use it in my function to get data from firebase :

```
      StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _productServices.getAnnouncesNearUser(
              _currentAddress == null ? '' : _currentAddress.toString()),
```

Answer (score 0):

please try using LocationAccuracy.medium,

Comment: the same I got Null